Error when registering inputs with React Hook Form with defaultValues
I am new to using React and React Hook Form, and am running into a typescript error (TS:2345) when I try to register a new input after assigning defaultValues for the form. I am creating a resume generator that watches for changes in the inputs and dynamically updates it on the resume.
The default value I am using is formatted like this:
export const defaultData = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@mail.com',
    number: '416-123-4567',
    address: 'California'
}

In my App component, I add my defaultValues with useForm()
function App(): JSX.Element {
  const { register, setValue, watch } = useForm({ defaultValues: defaultData });


Then, when I go on to register the inputs, i get the error:

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"number" | "name" | "email" | "address" (TS:2345)'

inputs={section.inputs.map((iField) => {
          const field = iField.field; //field is the name of the input property
          return (
            <div key={iField.id} className="inputField">
              <label>{iField.title}</label>
              <input
                {...register(field)}
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  setValue(field, e.target.value);
                }}
              ></input>
            </div>
          );
        })}

Any idea why I am getting this error? The properties in defaultData are all strings

The register function accept only string. Your field might be a string but with only specific list of strings "number" | "name" | "email" | "address".
So you have compatibility issue as string can be anything else...
You might want to change {...register(field)} to {...register(field as string)}
